# Custom data label for a single point in OHLC candlestick in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[This example shows](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-datalabels-box/) how you can set a custom data label for a single point for a simple X-Y chart:

In particular, point `216.4` appears as an object which carries its own styling for its data label. It is not an integer like the other values in `data` array:

```
 series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 178.0, 135.6, 148.5, {
        y: 216.4,
        dataLabels: {
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 2,
            padding: 5,
            shadow: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    }, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
```

I wanna do something similar, but with candlestick charts. In particular, how can I change the styling for the label of only one candle in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kwukv4by/4/

In the first example, the number is assigned to `y`. What should it be when data is `OHLC` instead of an integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the dataLables in the exact same way for a candlestick chart.  Just add the dataLables object to the point in the series.

http://jsfiddle.net/kwukv4by/10/

```
series: [{
      type: 'candlestick',
      name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
      data: [{
          time: 0,
          high: 100,
          low: 50,
          open: 60,
          close: 80,
          dataLabels: {
            borderRadius: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderWidth: 4,
            borderColor: 'black'
          }
        },
        {
          time: 1,
          high: 90,
          low: 50,
          open: 80,
          close: 70
        },
        {
          time: 2,
          high: 80,
          low: 10,
          open: 40,
          close: 60
        },
        {
          time: 3,
          high: 80,
          low: 10,
          open: 60,
          close: 40
        },
      ],

    }]
```